# LibGDX game crashing on android when more than 12 objects are added to a Table

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to make an online leaderboard for my game. The server-side part is okay, it runs well on the desktop version of the game.

However on Android it crashes without any warning. To get leaderboard data I use a HTTPUrlConnection request and then I parse the data with JsonReader class of LibGDX.

When I've parsed the data, this function

```
private void updateHighscoresTable(JsonValue value) {
    int count = value.getInt("count");

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        JsonValue child = value.get("" + i);

        String nickname = child.getString("nickname");
        int score = child.getInt("score");

        highscoresScreen.highscoresTable.center();
        highscoresScreen.highscoresTable.add(nickname).width(getCellWidth());
        highscoresScreen.highscoresTable.add("" + score);
        highscoresScreen.highscoresTable.row();

    }

    highscoresScreen.highscoresTable.setVisible(true);
}
```

insert everything in the highscores table. This table is draw on screen via a ScrollPane.
When there are more than 12 object the game will crash immediately before the table appear.

This is the code that initializes the Table and ScrollPane

```
    highscoresTable = new Table(skin);
    highscoresTable.setSize(460, 240);
    highscoresScrollPane = new ScrollPane(highscoresTable);
    highscoresScrollPane.setBounds(10, 40, 460, 240);

    highscoresScrollPane.setFadeScrollBars(false);
    highscoresTable.setVisible(false);
```

If I try to add 50 element right after creating the table, removing the for-loop in the previous function, it won't crash, but it's useless for me.
The JSON parsing it's okay, I added System.out.println in the for loop and everything was right.

I'm using the nightly version of the 14th February, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I only set highscoresTable to be hidden, when instead I should have set highscoresScrollPane to be hidden!

So:

```
highscoresScrollPane.setVisible(false)
```

resolved this issue.